# How to format dates and datetime in graphene

Tags: django, date, datetime, graphene-django

I want graphene to output normal date/datetime formats. By default it returns this:

```
`"createdAt": "2019-06-11T05:48:11.023255+00:00",`
```

And I want it to return this:

```
`"createdAt": "11.06.2019 11:48:11",`
```

It seems there is no such option in graphene dictionary, but still I want to use `graphene_django.DjangoObjectType` to use its Meta class, instead rewrite all fields w/ `graphene.ObjectType`

Answer (score 3):

You can overwrite any field with `DjangoObjectType`. Your code may look like this.

```
class CustomType(DjangoObjectType):

   class Meta:
      model = CustomModel


   created_at = graphene.String()

   def resolve_created_at(self, info):
      return str(self.created_at.replace(microsecond=0))
```

For more details check out the [docs](http://docs.graphene-python.org/projects/django/en/latest/queries/#customised-fields)

Comment: As I know you can't overwrite ANY field, only related objects or list fields. If it's a field inside Meta.field you cannot overwrite it, at least you don't add it into Meta.field but add field manually